# Pass arguments to PyCharm custom admin commands

Tags: django, pycharm

I'm testing out PyCharm and I bumped into an odd problem where I can't specify arguments to my custom admin commands. In the *Run/Debug Configurations* I added a runserver configuration, cleared the port and checked the *Custom run command* and added the name of my command.

That works fine, but when trying to run it with arguments such as `my_command 100` the console prints out `Unknown command: 'my_command 100'` which seems to happen when I run it manually adding quotes around the whole command.

Anyone knows where I can specify the arguments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Woops, got it, you add them to `Additional options` under the host/port.

Comment: where are these options?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue when trying to change the runserver to runserver_plus from django-extensions so that I can run with SSL turned on.

This works:

[image: pycharm and runserver_plus]

Comment: Thanks for the help :)